# Error C4430 - Object - Classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I created a object of the class LCalculation in another class,

```
class LCalculation
{
    public:
        unsigned __int64 m_Amount_of_Numbers;
        [...]
};
```

now I'm trying to use it and face those errors. It has something to do with this object declaration. I just don't get it. Could anyone help with this ? If more information is needed, feel free to ask.

---

---

```
class CMFC_App_CalculationDlg : public CDialogEx
{
private:
    LCalculation m_LCalc;
};
```

---

- 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation\mfc_app_calculationdlg.h(35): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_LCalc'
- 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation\mfc_app_calculationdlg.h(35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation\mfc_app_calculationdlg.h(35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

---

```
void CMFC_App_Calculation::OnEnChangeEdit2()
{
    m_LCalc.m_Amount_of_Numbers = UpdateData(TRUE);
}
```

---

- 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation\mfc_app_calculationdlg.cpp(191): error C2065: 'm_LCalc' : undeclared identifier
- 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation\mfc_app_calculationdlg.cpp(191): error C2228: left of '.m_Amount_of_Numbers' must have class/struct/union

  - type is ''unknown-type''

---

---

---

---

---

Get it, I'm new here. @Joachim Pileborg. Thanks.

**First header:**

```
// MFC_App_Calculation.h : main header file for the PROJECT_NAME application
//

#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols


// CMFC_App_CalculationApp:
// See MFC_App_Calculation.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CMFC_App_CalculationApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CMFC_App_CalculationApp();

// Overrides
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CMFC_App_CalculationApp theApp;
```

**Second header:**

```
// MFC_App_CalculationDlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once


// CMFC_App_CalculationDlg dialog
class CMFC_App_CalculationDlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CMFC_App_CalculationDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_APP_CALCULATION_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedRadio1();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedRadio2();
private:
    LCalculation m_LCalc;
public:
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit2();
};
```

**Third header:**

```
#pragma once
/*Comments*/
class LCalculation
{
    public:
        unsigned __int64 m_Amount_of_Numbers;
        unsigned __int64 m_Amount_of_Guesses;
        unsigned __int64 m_Probability;
        LCalculation ();
        bool m_bEqual;
        void CalculateThis ();
        void SZ_true ();
        void SZ_false ();
        void NUMBERequals (unsigned __int64 NUMBERS, unsigned __int64 GUESSES, unsigned __int16 IDENTIFIER);
};
```

Comment: Do you include the header file that defines `LCalcultation` in the header file that defines `CMFC_App_CalculationDlg`?

Comment: Can you please post the *complete* and *unedited* error messages? And also point out where in the source you have those errors.Also, what is `m_LottoBerechnung`?

Comment: Also, check your semicolons before the declaration of `m_LottoBerechnung`. It seems you are simply missing a couple.

Comment: This is the correct `unedited` Error code...

Comment: I'm not missing any semicolon, btw. It simply says I have to put one between `LCalculation m_LCalc;`.

Comment: What the errors are telling you, in a very non-obvious way, is that in the file `mfc_app_calculationdlg.h` the compiler doesn't know what `LCalculation` is. Are you sure you have included the file where `LCalculation` is defined *before* you include `mfc_app_calculationdlg.h`, or include it in `mfc_app_calculationdlg.h`?

Comment: 1. `#include "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Classes\CalcHeader.h"`
2. `#include "MFC_App_Calculation.h"`
3. `#include "MFC_App_CalculationDlg.h"`

Comment: IF you show us what's in those header files we might be able to help

Comment: I think it's time you try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and show us. It will probably help you realize what the problem is so you can solve it yourself.

Comment: @Blacktempel, something looks wrong in your relative path to `CalcHeader.h`: it goes to the parent directory seven times, and according to the current directory (`c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Calc\mfc_app_calculation`), this would end up one level *above* `c:\ `.

Comment: I got the files for the LCalculation class in my `C:\Classes` directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second header (MFC_App_CalculationDlg.h) you forgot to `#include "LCalculation.h"` or however you named the third header.

And BTW, UpdateData returns a BOOL, not an amount_of_numbers. You should read the documentation for UpdateData and DoDataExchange to better understand how MFC is doing data exchange from/to dialog controls.

Comment: Actually it was the second header, but thanks. I got it a min ago.

Comment: Yes, I just saw and corrected that (also gave the name of the h file now).